# How to format time into dd:hh:mm using moment.js?

Tags: momentjs

I have a current format HH:mm:ss, but I want to convert it into dd:hh:mm. Is this possible in moment.js?

Comment: Refer the  documentation you can figure out it easily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing, I feel like you don't have a date here, you have a duration. Note that moment can handle those as well, but it handles them differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var dateTime = new Date("2016-04-12 10:24:36");
dateTime = moment(dateTime).format("DD HH:mm");
```

Comment: Thanks @Prabhat for the answering. I'll look on to the docs more from now on.